# Differentiation ...

Tags: derivatives

Would this be a correct differentiation :

$d(\sqrt[3]{1-x^3})=(-x^2*dx)/(1-x^3)^\frac{2}{3}$

I don't know why, but the textbook shows me this answer :

$-\sqrt[2]{(1-x^3)^2}*dx$

Can somebody guide me ? Thank yoU!

Comment: I don't know why either:  it looks like they forgot to print the "chain-rule" factor.  There _should_ be a factor of $ \ x^2 \ $ in the answer.

Comment: So, it would be an error ? ...

Comment: Sure would -- somehow the minus sign made it in, so I think there's an omission "typo".

Comment: Yeah, I think that's it. Thank you for your time !

Comment: Oh, by the way, I just noticed that it's not a cuberoot that's given but a square root. what.... (In the textbook)

Comment: Where is that?  You _have_ a cube-root typed in your post.

Comment: Yeah, that was an error from my part. What the textbook says is the following : -squareroot((1-x^3)^2)*dx

Comment: Well, it looks like a mangled result: a square-root there is a bit silly.  You have carried out the differentiation correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$g(x)=1-x^3$$

Clearly $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$

Then by the chain rule:
$$[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
Replacing:
$$[f(g(x))]'=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(1-x^3)^{\frac{2}{3}}}(-3x^2)=\frac{-x^2}{(1-x^3)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

So you're right

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=(1-x^3)^{1/3}$

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx} = 1/3(1-x^3)^{-2/3}(-3x^2)$$

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx} = -x^2/(1-x^3)^{2/3}$$

so yes you are correct!

The book probably had a typing mistake